# How to send binary data in netcat to an already established connection?

Tags: networking, tcp, netcat, binary

I can do the following to send binary data in netcat:

```
echo -e '\x80' | nc host port
```

But I don't want to do it like this, what I want is to connect to a server:

```
nc 192.168.1.115 12345
```

And then send some text:

```
aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc
```

And then send some binary data:

```
0x80 0xF4 0x12
```

How can I do that?

Comment: why is using `echo` not possible?